# Is there a way to stop CKeditor placing <cite></cite> elements INSIDE the quotation marks of a blockquote

Tags: html, ckeditor4.x

When adding a citation to a blockquote, the citation is wrapped in the quotation marks rather than appearing AFTER the quotation marks.

i.e:

"quote -citation"

instead of

"quote" -citation

I've created a filter, using regex that prevents the problem when published:

```
preg_replace('|<p>\s*<cite>(.*?)</cite>\s*</p>|', '<cite>$1</cite>', $text));
```

HOWEVER, the wysiwyg editor still displays the fault.

Im not really familiar with adapting CKEditor or whereabouts I should write my code. Can anybody help? I just need a way to prevent ckeditor from creating P tags around a CITE tag within the wysiwyg editor.